stop ggplot from drawing lines over na values
I'm creating a bump chart to show changes in the rankings of the top 10 values over a period of 10 years. When something drops out of the top 10 I'm keeping the value it drops to, to show how far down the ranks an item falls. However if it rejoins the top 10 then I want it to have a break between the two. However at the moment it looks like this:

Here is the function that I am using to generate this chart at the moment:
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = rank_pos, color = category)) +
    geom_point(size=8) +
    geom_bump(size=1.5) +
    geom_text(aes(label = rank), size = 6,color = "white") +
    geom_text(data=start_data, aes(x = year-0.5, y = rank, label = category), hjust="right",colour="black",size = 5)+
    geom_text(data=end_data, aes(x = year+0.5, y = rank, label = category), hjust="left",colour="black",size = 5)+
    geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(rank == 1, year, "")), size = 4, hjust = 0.5, vjust = -3,colour="black")+
    scale_colour_manual(values = colours) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 1, size=13),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())+
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse", breaks = unique(df$rank),expand=c(0.1,0.0)) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0.25,0.25),position = "top") +
    xlab("Year")

The rank position I am going to adjust but I need to know how to create a break e.g. with the bottom black rank needs a gap between 2014 and 2020.
ETA:
structure(list(category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
"F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"), class = "factor"), year = c(2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022), 
    rank = c(9L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 12L, 
    10L, 10L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 10L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
    7L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 19L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 11L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11L, 
    10L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 11L, NA, NA, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), rank_pos = c(9, 7, 7, 8, 8, 7, 10, 
    8, 9, 5, 6, 11, 10, 10, 9, 6, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 5, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 4, 4, 6, 6, 9, 9, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 
    3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 
    8, 8, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11, 7, 9, 9, 8, 8, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 11, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    11, 10, 5, 6, 9, 10, 10, 10, 9, 10, 11, NA, NA, 2, 2, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -132L), groups = structure(list(
    category= structure(1:12, levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
    "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:11, 12:22, 23:33, 34:44, 45:55, 
        56:66, 67:77, 78:88, 89:99, 100:110, 111:121, 122:132), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L), .drop = TRUE))


Could you please share some reproducible data using dput?

Unfortunately your example data is lacking a year column.

This is difficult to reproduce as, in addition to year, it's also missing gss_colours and category in the data. And countries "C" and "K" are not fully quoted.

I fixed it, apologies

One possible approach could be to set rank_pos to 12 for the gaps, then either

Use coord_cartesian() to "zoom in" on only the parts you want visible
Or use annotate("rect", ymin = 11.5, ymax = 12.5, xmin = 2011, xmax = 2023, fill = "white") to hide a rank_pos of 12.

library(tidyverse)
library(ggbump)

df |> 
  mutate(rank_pos = replace_na(rank_pos, 12)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = rank_pos, color = category)) +
  geom_point(size = 8) +
  geom_bump(size = 1.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = rank), size = 6, color = "white") +
  # geom_text(data=start_data, aes(x = year-0.5, y = rank, label = category), hjust="right",colour="black",size = 5)+
  # geom_text(data=end_data, aes(x = year+0.5, y = rank, label = category), hjust="left",colour="black",size = 5)+
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(rank == 1, year, "")), size = 4, hjust = 0.5, vjust = -3, colour = "black") +
  # scale_colour_manual(values = colours) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 1, size = 13),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse", breaks = unique(df$rank_pos), expand = c(0.1, 0.0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.25, 0.25), position = "top") +
  xlab("Year") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(10.5, 0))


Created on 2024-05-02 with reprex v2.1.0
